# Flutter Overflow in Stack

Tags: flutter

I have a `Stack` widget in which I have a bunch of other widgets that have text and icons on them. They are shown on the the screen at the same time using a `PageView`. When going to landscape mode on the phone they get an overflow. I cant prevent it using `FittedBox`, `Flexible`, `Expanded`, `SingleChildScrollView` etc., because its in a `Stack` and that causes `Invalid use of ParentDataWidget`. I have solved the problem using a lot of ugly conditional rendering and an `OverflowBox` but im sure there is a more elegant solution, so does anyone know how to solve it using something like `Expanded`?

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'contact.dart';

class ContactCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContactCard(
      {Key? key, required this.borderColor, required this.contact})
      : super(key: key);

  final Color borderColor;
  final Contact contact;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Align(
          heightFactor: .9,
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 70,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: borderColor,
                borderRadius:
                    const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10))),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: borderColor,
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.person_outlined,
                      size: 40,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text.rich(TextSpan(
                            text: contact.name,
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                text: '\n${contact.role}',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15),
                              )
                            ],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ))))
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.home_outlined,
                      size: 40,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text.rich(TextSpan(
                      text: contact.address,
                    )))
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.phone_outlined,
                      size: 40,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text.rich(
                      TextSpan(
                        text: contact.phone,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 156, 78, 170)),
                      ),
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.mail_outline,
                      size: 40,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Text.rich(TextSpan(
                      text: contact.mail,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 156, 78, 170)),
                    )))
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**And:**

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'contact.dart';
import 'contact_card.dart';

class ContactsListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContactsListPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          drawer: Drawer(
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[400],
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
            child: ListView(
              // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: [
                const ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    "Navigation",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider(thickness: 3),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Item 1'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Item 2'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text(
              "TEMPLATES",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(20))),
            leading: Builder(builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.menu));
            }),
            actions: [
              IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.search))
            ],
          ),
          body: PerspectiveListView(
            frontItemTapped: (value) =>
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Center(child: (Text("test #$value"))),
            )),
            visibleItems: 8, //possibly null format
            itemExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
            initialIndex: 7, //null format
            backItemsShadowColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            children: List.generate(Contact.contacts.length, (index) {
              final contact = Contact.contacts[index];
              final borderColor = Colors.accents[index % Colors.accents.length];
              return ContactCard(
                borderColor: borderColor,
                contact: contact,
              );
            }),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class PerspectiveListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const PerspectiveListView({
    Key? key,
    required this.children,
    required this.itemExtent,
    required this.visibleItems,
    this.initialIndex = 0,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    this.frontItemTapped,
    this.changedItem,
    this.backItemsShadowColor = Colors.black,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Widget> children;
  final double itemExtent;
  final int visibleItems;
  final int initialIndex;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;
  final ValueChanged<int>? frontItemTapped;
  final ValueChanged<int>? changedItem;
  final Color backItemsShadowColor;

  @override
  State<PerspectiveListView> createState() => _PerspectiveListViewState();
}

class _PerspectiveListViewState extends State<PerspectiveListView> {
  late PageController _pageController;
  late double _pagePercent;
  late int _currentIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = PageController(
        initialPage: widget.initialIndex,
        viewportFraction:
            1 / widget.visibleItems); //viewport frac = scroll speed
    _currentIndex = widget.initialIndex;
    _pagePercent = 0.0;
    _pageController.addListener(_pageListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.removeListener(_pageListener);
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _pageListener() {
    _currentIndex = _pageController.page!.floor();
    _pagePercent = (_pageController.page! - _currentIndex).abs();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      final height = constraints.maxHeight;
      return Stack(children: [
        //Items
        Padding(
            padding: widget.padding,
            child: _PerspectiveItems(
              currentIndex: _currentIndex,
              generatedItems: widget.visibleItems - 1,
              heightItem: widget.itemExtent,
              pagePercent: _pagePercent,
              children: widget.children,
            )),
        Positioned.fill(
            child: DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                widget.backItemsShadowColor.withOpacity(.6),
                widget.backItemsShadowColor.withOpacity(0)
              ])),
        )),
        //Void Page View
        PageView.builder(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          controller: _pageController,
          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          onPageChanged: (value) {
            widget.changedItem?.call(value);
          },
          itemCount: widget.children.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return const SizedBox();
          },
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
            top: height - widget.itemExtent,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => widget.frontItemTapped?.call(_currentIndex),
            ))
      ]);
    });
  }
}

class _PerspectiveItems extends StatelessWidget {
  const _PerspectiveItems({
    Key? key,
    required this.generatedItems,
    required this.currentIndex,
    required this.heightItem,
    required this.pagePercent,
    required this.children,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int generatedItems;
  final int currentIndex;
  final double heightItem;
  final double pagePercent;
  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      final height = constraints.maxHeight;
      return Stack(
          children: List.generate(generatedItems, (index) {
        final invertedIndex = (generatedItems- 2) - index;
        final indexPlus = index + 1;
        final positionPercent = indexPlus / generatedItems;
        final endPositionPercent = index / generatedItems;
        return currentIndex > invertedIndex
            ? _TransformedItem(
                heightItem: heightItem,
                factorChange: pagePercent,
                scale: lerpDouble(.5, 1, positionPercent)!,
                endScale: lerpDouble(.5, 1, endPositionPercent)!,
                translateY: (height - heightItem) * positionPercent,
                endTranslateY: (height - heightItem) * endPositionPercent,
                child: children[currentIndex - (invertedIndex + 1)],
              )
            : const SizedBox();
      })
            ..add(currentIndex < (children.length - 1)
                ? _TransformedItem(
                    heightItem: heightItem,
                    factorChange: pagePercent,
                    translateY: height + (local == generatedItems ? 30 : 100),
                    endTranslateY: height - heightItem,
                    child: children[currentIndex + 1],
                  )
                : const SizedBox())
            ..insert(
                0,
                (currentIndex > (generatedItems - 1)
                    ? _TransformedItem(
                        heightItem: heightItem,
                        factorChange: 1.0,
                        endScale: 0.5,
                        child: children[currentIndex - generatedItems],
                      )
                    : const SizedBox())));
    });
  }
}

class _TransformedItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const _TransformedItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.heightItem,
    required this.factorChange,
    this.scale = 1.0,
    this.endScale = 1.0,
    this.translateY = 0.0,
    this.endTranslateY = 0.0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final double heightItem;
  final double factorChange;
  final double scale;
  final double endScale;
  final double translateY;
  final double endTranslateY;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      transform: Matrix4.identity()
        ..scale(lerpDouble(scale, endScale, factorChange))
        ..translate(
            0.0, lerpDouble(translateY, endTranslateY, factorChange)!, 0.0),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: heightItem,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════

    A RenderFlex overflowed by 81 pixels on the bottom.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Column
```

Comment: please add code and error trace with ss.